# Web load testing, difference between different client thread numbers

Tags: performance, load-testing, web-testing

we are doing web load testing to check how our web API perform on a specific QPS (query per second).

We have a tool to send request to our web API.

My questions is,
For a given QPS, say 100, with different combination of number of client threads and requests per a thread, what is difference on Web API side.

E.g.,

- 1 thread, 100 requests per second per thread
- 10 threads, 10 requests per second per thread
- 20 threads, 5 requests per second per thread.

Any difference on capacity of web API server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From server side it should be no difference, however you scenarios may not be applicable. I don't know your "tool" details, but normally web API means [HTTP transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and HTTP is "request/response" protocol so given you use 1 thread you won't be able to send the next request until you receive response from the server.

Normal "good" practice is simulating the load as close to reality as possible so you need to mimic real life usage of your web API, otherwise your load test does not make sense. So I would recommend reconsidering your load pattern to represent either real user or application which is using web API as close as possible. See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide for some insights.

Answer (score 0):

A thread is simulating a real user, so, let's say that when you set 10 threads, 10 requests per second per thread mean that 10 users are making 10 requests per second each one.

A performance tool is basically simulating users doing clicks on the website, so each click represents a request.

Since each request will make use of the API, it means that every request will generate load on the server. If you notice that the requests are taking longer as the tests are running, then it means that you are reaching the limit of your environment's capacity. If the number of users and requests per second is low, then you need to tune up your code and queries to get the fastest response possible. Once you do everything possible on the code side, you may need to get a stronger server depending on your project's requirements.

The goal of those tests is to determine if your website is capable of serving the required number of users.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for trying to help. However, your answer seems to explain the purpose of performance test tools and the possible measures to take in case of unsatisfactory speed. OP however asks about the difference of distributing 100 qps to different numbers of threads. Your answer seems to not discuss this specific point and hence seems not to actually answer the question.